# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No process is associated with this object.'

Tags: c#

```
public static void Process(string state)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = Global.filepath + @"\PhoenixMiner.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = Global.command;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            if (state == "start")
            {
                p.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                p.Kill(); //Error happens here
            }
        }
```

How can I kill the process correctly?
I tried some methods that were given in other answers but none seem to work.

Comment: Well if you haven't started a process, and you haven't got an existing one, what do you expect to happen? After all, `PhoenixMiner.exe` may not be unique, there may be more of them. There is no functionality to just `Kill` whichever process which happens to have that image name. Perhaps you want `Process.GetProcessesByName`

Comment: @Charlieface so how can i both start a process by pressing a button and kill it by pressing it again?
The process is unique theres only one running

Comment: Presumably, if you want to `Kill` the process started by the same button, then you have to store `p` (from when you launched it) in a field/property somewhere. I note that `Kill` is a pretty brutal way of ending an app, you may want to look at `Process.CloseMainWindow` or better, some kind of inter-process communication

Comment: It would be better to have two methods. The first returns the process, which can be saved off somewhere. The second would do the kill. A single method does too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the process in between clicks.

```
    private static Process p = null;

    public static void Process(string state)
    {
        if (state == "start" && p == null)
        {
            p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = Global.filepath + @"\PhoenixMiner.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = Global.command;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.Start();
        }
        if (state != "start" && p != null)
        {
            p.Kill();
            p.Dispose();
            p = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely because you are trying to `kill` a `Process` which is not yet started, as per your `if-else` case.

```
public static void InitProcess()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = Global.filepath + @"\PhoenixMiner.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = Global.command;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    p.Start();     
    Thread.Sleep(2000); 
    p.kill();
}
```

If you want to kill the process on condition basis, better to move the process `kill` block *(else block in your case)* to separate method and check the running process before you invoke kill.

```
Process[]  runingProcess= Process.GetProcesses();
```

Also, have a look at overloaded method `Process.Kill(false)` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-5.0)